# Leaflet map not showing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dictionary, leaflet

I have a leaflet map correctly working inside a simple HTML page.

When I move that exact map from the HTML page into a Wordpress page template, the map tiles don't show up anymore. The strange thing is that I'm using some geoJSON shapes and they show up fine, but the map itself doesn't. Here is a screenshot

[image]

All relative files are loading correctly, no errors in the console. Here is the code I'm using to initialise the map:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.504, -0.021], 17);


L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/jeffceriello.mngoo42b/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamVmZmNlcmllbGxvIiwiYSI6Ikhrakxrd00ifQ.SlVngzIXeS5UPC8UGmy1OA', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent;

    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.title) {
        popupContent = feature.properties.title;
    }

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}

L.geoJson([campus], {

    style: function (feature) {
        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
    },

    onEachFeature: onEachFeature

}).addTo(map);
```

Here is a screenshot of all the files included:

CSS line 106

leaflet.js line 119

map script 121

[image]

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need some js library to be included?

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of the library included

Comment: I think you ned to add http to those //.... urls or maybe download them locally for faster access

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something is blocking mapbox tiles? Try using OSM layer to verify. Replace your tile layer with the code below and see if it is any better.

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom : 19
}).addTo(map)
```